# React Native AsyncStorage Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I'm trying to do appeared simple, but I'm having some major issues.  I have a post login JSON object that I want to save and retrieve from AsyncStorage.  I know you can't save a JSON object to storage and it must be stringified... did this and when I go try to get it out, it doesn't seem to be retuning the way intended.

Code

Login.js

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem("loginData", JSON.stringify(result.data));
await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", result.data.token);
props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

Home.js

```
export default function Home (props) {
    
    let resData = {};
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    let announcementData = {};
    let portalTipsData = {};

    getAsyncStorage = async(key) => {
        try {
          const getAsyncStorageData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
          const getAsyncStorageParsed = JSON.parse(getAsyncStorageData);
          return getAsyncStorageParsed;
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        }
    }

    getAsyncStorage("loginData").then((result) => {
        resData = result;
        announcementData = resData.Announcements;
        portalTipsData = resData.PortalTips; 

        console.log("Test 1: ", announcementData);
        console.log("Test 2: ", portalTipsData);
    });
```

Whats weird is when I try to use the annoucmentData or the portalTipsData, I get an error saying the Objects are not valid as React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65 ...
This is not the way the data should look, I believe its something dumb on my end that I'm missing hoping you all can call me on it.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show what is logged when you do a `console.log` for the object? Also you should include the `render()` method if the error you encounter is there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, you must stringify your object.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem("loginData", JSON.stringify(result.Data), (err)=> {
    if(err){
        console.log("Something bad happened :(");
    }
    console.log("Boom!");
}).catch((err)=> {
    console.log("error is: " + err);
});
```

And when you read it, you should parse it.

```
try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("loginData");
    if (value !== null) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(value));
    }
} catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
}
```

If that does not work then maybe check the value of result.Data

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code provided above and found that the relevant fields can be accessed normally. I think your use of AsyncStorage above does not have any problems. It may be that your other usage is wrong. However, for the use of AsyncStorage, we recommend you an open source library [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md), through which you can use AsyncStorage more conveniently and quickly.

```
  import { XStorage } from 'react-native-easy-app';
  import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
  // or import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

   export const RNStorage = {
       token: undefined, 
       isShow: undefined, 
       userInfo: undefined
   };
   
  const initCallback = () => {

       // From now on, you can write or read the variables in RNStorage synchronously
       
       // equal to [console.log(await AsyncStorage.getItem('isShow'))]
       console.log(RNStorage.isShow); 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3==') ]
       RNStorage.token = 'TOKEN1343DN23IDD3PJ2DBF3=='; 
       
       // equal to [ await AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo',JSON.stringify({ name:'rufeng', age:30})) ]
       RNStorage.userInfo = {name: 'rufeng', age: 30}; 
  };
  
  XStorage.initStorage(RNStorage, AsyncStorage, initCallback);
```